# Change default italic from <i> to <em> in admin editor

Tags: admin, editor, content, text

I've noticed that the admin editor by default embeds any italic texts with `<i>` which I intend to use for icon styling. I much more prefer to wrap them with an `<em>`. How would I got about changing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure editor use `<i>` for italics? I'm almost sure it uses `<em>`.

However, if you want to be absolutely sure there are no `<i>` in your post content, let editor do what it want and then replace `<i>` with `<em>` before creating/updating posts, hooking `wp_insert_post_data` filter, just like:

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data','replace_em', 20, 1);

function replace_em( $post_data ) {
  if ( $post_data['post_content'] != '' ) {
    $post_data['post_content'] = str_ireplace( array('<i>', '</i>'), array('<em>', '</em>'), $post_data['post_content'] );
  }
  return $post_data;
}
```

Even if you insert `<i>` manually, they are replaced with `<em>` on saving.